# Pass back a value from Open Policy Agent (OPA) query

Tags: policy, open-policy-agent, rego

Instead of seeing who can access what, I want to setup policies that return how many connections are allowed per second, or, how much bandwidth is allowed.  How do I define my policies to return values instead of true/false?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Complete rules](https://www.openpolicyagent.org/docs/latest/#complete-rules) are just if-then statements that assign a VALUE to a VARIABLE. When the VALUE is omitted, it's implicitly `true`:

```
allow { input.method == "GET" }
```

Is equivalent to:

```
allow = true { input.method == "GET" }
```

There is nothing special about `allow` or `true` though; you could similarly define a rule that sets the connections per second limit:

```
connections_per_second = 7 { input.tier == "gold" }
```

If you have multiple definitions just be aware that only *one* can succeed (otherwise OPA will raise a conflict error). You need to resolve the conflict inside of your policy. There are different ways of handling this, e.g., `default`, `else`, negation, etc.

Comment: Thanks :) I see you answering a lot of OPA questions.  Is Stack Overflow the best place to ask OPA questions, or is there some place else?

Comment: SO is great because then other people can find the answer more easily. If you run into issues or have questions about features, then GitHub is a bit better. For Q&A like this, SO is perfect :)

Comment: is there a way to add a schema to the return value? e.g. for cases where I need to return a JSON string, to make sure it has the 'expected' format